# Cant construct mysql select query without subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE logs(
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ip INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` TIMESTAMP,
  `time` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  referrer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  uri VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
)
```

And I need to fetch following data and group then by IP:

- IP
- referrer that was first for IP (date is min.)
- last visited uri for IP
- number of unique uris

Is it possible to write such query without subqueries?

My solution WITH subqueries:

```
SELECT
    `logs`.`ip`,
    (SELECT
        `tmp`.`referrer`
    FROM
        `logs` AS `tmp`
    WHERE
        `tmp`.`ip` = `logs`.`ip`
    ORDER BY `tmp`.`date`
    LIMIT 1) 'referrer',
    (SELECT
        `tmp`.`uri`
    FROM
        `logs` AS `tmp`
    WHERE
        `tmp`.`ip` = `logs`.`ip`
    ORDER BY
        `tmp`.`date` DESC
    LIMIT 1) 'uri',
    COUNT(DISTINCT (`logs`.`uri`)) 'urls'
FROM
    `logs`
GROUP BY
    `logs`.`ip`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    `logs`.`ip`,
    `tmp`.`referrer`
    `tmp`.`uri`
    count(distinct `logs`.`uri`)) as `urls`
from `logs`
left join `tmp` on `tmp`.`ip`=`logs`.`ip`
group by `logs`.`ip`
```

However this doesn't allow for the `order by tmp.date` part. If it's absolutely required, let me know in a comment and I'll update this code to allow that.